# Dropbox headless crashes "could not connect to display :1"

Tags: server, dropbox, headless

I installed dropbox from https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux as described to installed it headless. However when I try to run it I get the following error at the end ouf a list of outputs:

```
[simernes@simernes ~]$ dropbox start
Starting Dropbox...dropbox: locating interpreter
dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-HaMTae
dropbox: initializing
dropbox: initializing python 3.7.2
dropbox: setting program path '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/dropbox'
dropbox: setting home path '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126'
dropbox: setting python path '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126:/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/python-packages-37.zip'
dropbox: python initialized
dropbox: running dropbox
dropbox: setting args
dropbox: applying overrides
dropbox: running main script
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/linuxffi.pthread._linuxffi_pthread.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/cpuid.compiled._cpuid.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/apex._apex.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/linuxffi.resolv.compiled._linuxffi_resolv.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/tornado.speedups.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/librsyncffi.compiled._librsyncffi.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/linuxffi.sys.compiled._linuxffi_sys.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/posixffi.libc._posixffi_libc.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/linuxffi.gnu.compiled._linuxffi_gnu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/PyQt5.QtCore.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/PyQt5.QtGui.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/PyQt5.QtWidgets.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/PyQt5.QtNetwork.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/simernes/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-76.4.126/PyQt5.QtDBus.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
No protocol specified
b'!! (Qt:Fatal) QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1'
Dropbox isn't running!
Done!
```

I previously had installed Dropbox from the dropbox repository, but I want to run dropbox in a headless user at startup, so I deleted the previously created ~/.dropbox and ~/.dropbox-dist .

Anything I can do? The end goal is that I can run Dropbox as a headless daemon at startup, possibly in a @reboot entry in crontab.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
dropbox start
```

is not the correct command to start dropbox and since it wants a display it probably is the one to use on a desktop system. The command used in the link is

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

That starts the daemon (the last "d" in dropboxd).

Comment: Good catch, you're right! However, I still get the error `b'!! (Qt:Fatal) QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1'`. Someone else had an answer saying that I should start it with the environment variable DISPLAY='', i.e with your recommendation it would be: `DISPLAY='' ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and then it works. For some reason they removed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
export DISPLAY=:0 
dropbox start
```